# Azure - Why command "yes" causes infite loop?

Tags: azure, cmd, kudu

If in Microsoft Azure in Kudu in Debug Console I type "yes" it hangs in infinite loop:

```
D:\home> yes
y
y
y
y
...
```

Why?

Comment: what does `where yes` say?

Comment: @Stephan `D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\yes.exe`

Comment: That's the proof, Michael is right.

Answer (score 8):

`yes` is a Unix/Linux command that was originally intended (think early 80's) to answer 'y' to file queries (etc) to delete multiple files (etc) before there was an 'all' option.

So the purpose is to answer 'y' everytime it gets a newline in the pipe.

On azure it has been carried in as part of the git installation (if you check it is in the `D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\yes.exe`)

If it has been built with the same specification as the original `yes` command, it should also consume 100% of the CPU

Comment: It's all part of having a positive attitude. But if that's not your thing, try running 'yes no' instead. :)

Comment: @DavidEbbo mostly it makes me think of bad eighties romcoms!

Comment: I do find it impressive that a command that was originally created on early Unix systems in the eighties (possibly 70s) is now running against massively scalable cloud platforms. (I may have just spent the last hour trying to find its origin!)

Comment: for anyone who is curious about the history of `yes` I asked a question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288441/174124